# How to transform nd array to plot feature importances using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, shap

I am using [`shap`](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) to determine feature importances for an [`mlp_classifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html).

(Note - I am using dummy data and model because my normal data and model are proprietary).

```
import shap, pandas as pd, numpy as np
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

data = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                     columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])
label = data['target']
data.drop('target', axis=1, inplace=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, label,random_state=np.random.randint(1,10), test_size=0.3)

mlp = MLPClassifier(max_iter=150).fit(X_train, y_train)                                            
mlp.score(X_test, y_test)

explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(mlp.predict_proba, shap.kmeans(X_train, 5))
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)

# First plot
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[1], feature_names = X_test.columns, plot_type='bar')

# Second, error, empty plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
y_pos = np.arange(len(X_test.columns))
plt.bar(y_pos, shap_values[1], align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, X_test.columns)
plt.ylabel('SHAP Importance')
plt.title('MLP Feature Importances')

plt.show()
```

Using `shap.summary_plot` by following [this guide](http://www.statsoft.org/wp-content/uploads/2019Stat3612SML/Tutorial7/Tutorial7.html), I get a plot like the following:

[image]

In my actual dataset, I have about `10,000` features. What I am looking to do, is take the top `n` features from that list, and plot them using `matplotlib`, by following [this guide](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-bar-chart/). However, I get an error and a blank graph:

[image]

Full Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-ba03083152ca> in <module>
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
      2 y_pos = np.arange(len(X_test.columns))
----> 3 plt.bar(y_pos, shap_values[1], align='center', alpha=0.5)
      4 plt.xticks(y_pos, X_test.columns)
      5 plt.ylabel('SHAP Importance')

c:\python367-64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in bar(x, height, width, bottom, align, data, **kwargs)
   2407     return gca().bar(
   2408         x, height, width=width, bottom=bottom, align=align,
-> 2409         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2410 
   2411 

c:\python367-64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1563     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1564         if data is None:
-> 1565             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1566 
   1567         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

c:\python367-64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in bar(self, x, height, width, bottom, align, **kwargs)
   2393                 edgecolor=e,
   2394                 linewidth=lw,
-> 2395                 label='_nolegend_',
   2396                 )
   2397             r.update(kwargs)

c:\python367-64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py in __init__(self, xy, width, height, angle, **kwargs)
    725         """
    726 
--> 727         Patch.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    728 
    729         self._x0 = xy[0]

c:\python367-64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py in __init__(self, edgecolor, facecolor, color, linewidth, linestyle, antialiased, hatch, fill, capstyle, joinstyle, **kwargs)
     87         self.set_fill(fill)
     88         self.set_linestyle(linestyle)
---> 89         self.set_linewidth(linewidth)
     90         self.set_antialiased(antialiased)
     91         self.set_hatch(hatch)

c:\python367-64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py in set_linewidth(self, w)
    393                 w = mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth']
    394 
--> 395         self._linewidth = float(w)
    396         # scale the dash pattern by the linewidth
    397         offset, ls = self._us_dashes

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I am having trouble mapping the `shap_value` in `shap_values[1]` to a specific feature in `X_test.columns`. How can I do this to properly take the top `n` and plot in `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `shap_values[1]` are feature importances. So you can turn it into a series:

```
# features importances sorted 
fi = (pd.Series(shap_values[1].mean(0), index=X_test.columns)
        .abs()
        .sort_values(ascending=False)
     )

# extract 5 top values and plot
fi.head(5).plot.barh()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: is it possible to turn this into a `dataframe` instead of a series? Ultimately, I want to customize the plot (colorscheme, tick marks, size, etc) and am more familiar working with dataframes than series.

Comment: Yes, you can do `pd.DataFrame({'fi':shap_values[1].mean(0)}, index=X_test.columns)`. But basically, most of the plotting you do with DataFrame is also available for series.